# Driver Circuit for 10W LED

Tags: led

[image: 10W LED Driver]

I need to understand the 10w led driver circuit shown in image.

Comment: what do you mean by `understand` ? ..... that is a horrible schematic, by the way .... where did that come from?

Comment: I got that from web, I am unable to understand that why npn transistor is used there?

Comment: it looks like someone on the internet just adjusted things until they got the result they wanted.  They could have got the same result with a single resistor

Answer (score 3):

This is the same schematic.

Which part do you not understand?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVGXVF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: +1 for taking the trouble to re-draw the circuit in a **proper** form, this is how it should have been drawn in the question. Anyway: it's a **pointless** schematic. **One power-resistor** can do the same job as Q1, R2, R1. There is no need for L1 and C1 isn't really needed either. Also this is a **very inefficient** way to power a 10 W LED from 12 V.